# TSQL: Select set of rows that share a single column value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm running MSSQL Server 2016 Express. I want to select all rows that have a certain `articlegroup_id` value and select the rows that have matching `articleid` values.

So, using the data below, let's say I want to get the resultset for `articlegroup_id` with value 684.
Only articleid's 3107196 and 3100000 match on this. So the result set would be:

```
3100000 129
3100000 144
3100000 684
3107196 129
3107196 144
3107196 684
```

Similarly if I run the same query on `articlegroup_id` with value 112 I want to get:

```
2106543 110
2106543 112
2106999 110
2106999 112
```

**DDL**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[products_category_mapping](
    [articleid] [int] NOT NULL,
    [articlegroup_id] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO products_category_mapping(articleid,articlegroup_id) VALUES (3100000,129)
INSERT INTO products_category_mapping(articleid,articlegroup_id) VALUES (3100000,144)
INSERT INTO products_category_mapping(articleid,articlegroup_id) VALUES (3100000,684)

INSERT INTO products_category_mapping(articleid,articlegroup_id) VALUES (3107196,129)
INSERT INTO products_category_mapping(articleid,articlegroup_id) VALUES (3107196,144)
INSERT INTO products_category_mapping(articleid,articlegroup_id) VALUES (3107196,684)

INSERT INTO products_category_mapping(articleid,articlegroup_id) VALUES (3107100,129)
INSERT INTO products_category_mapping(articleid,articlegroup_id) VALUES (3107100,144)

INSERT INTO products_category_mapping(articleid,articlegroup_id) VALUES (2106543,110)
INSERT INTO products_category_mapping(articleid,articlegroup_id) VALUES (2106543,112)

INSERT INTO products_category_mapping(articleid,articlegroup_id) VALUES (2107000,110)

INSERT INTO products_category_mapping(articleid,articlegroup_id) VALUES (2106999,110)
INSERT INTO products_category_mapping(articleid,articlegroup_id) VALUES (2106999,112)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use subquery to find the articleids for a give articlegroupid and then get all the rows with matching articleids

```
select * 
from products_category_mapping
where articleid in (
    select articleid
    from products_category_mapping
    where articlegroup_id = 684
)
```

Another way is using join:

```
select p1.* 
from products_category_mapping p1
inner join products_category_mapping p2
on p1.articleid = p2.articleid
and p2.articlegroup_id = 684;
```

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is to use a JOIN

```
Select A.*
 From  [products_category_mapping] A
 Join (
        Select articleid from [products_category_mapping] where articlegroup_id=684
      ) B on A.articleid=B.articleid
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it:

```
DECLARE @articlegroup_id int = 112 
;WITH CTE 
AS
(
    SELECT articleid
    FROM products_category_mapping
    WHERE articlegroup_id = @articlegroup_id
)

SELECT articleid, articlegroup_id
FROM products_category_mapping main
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM CTE 
    WHERE CTE.articleid = main.articleid
    )
```

Results:

```
articleid   articlegroup_id
2106543     110
2106543     112
2106999     110
2106999     112
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, There is no version called `SQL Server 2015`

About the Solution, use sub-query in `where` clause like this:-

```
select * from [products_category_mapping]
where articleid in (
    select articleid 
    from [products_category_mapping] where articlegroup_id  = 684)
```

**Result:-**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can use exists to do thes:

```
select * products_category_mapping products1
where exists (select null from products_category_mapping products2
where products1.articleid = products2.articleid
and products2.articlegroup_id = 684);
```